# Lock table in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, locking

Can I lock table through command SELECT in Oracle database? (without use SELECT...FOR UPDATE or SELECT...LOCK IN SHARE MODE, because this are commands lock rows)?

thanks in advance

Comment: No. The only way to lock the entire table is to use [`LOCK TABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01605)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you!